# Can Execute my query in database but when trying in Birt exception aries

Tags: birt

when i am trying to execute this query in Birt:

```
select a.ag_code , COUNT(distinct(a.usr_id)),b.AG_NAME
from photo a, 
     (select ag_code,AG_NAME from  agent 
      WHERE AG_TYPE = 'AS' AND AG_USEFLAG = 'Y' AND AG_NAME LIKE 'M%')b
where a.upload_time BETWEEN TO_DATE('20131116000000','yyyymmddhh24miss')
                        AND TO_DATE('20131129235959','yyyymmddhh24miss')
  and a.status = 'S'
  and a.ag_code = b.ag_code
group by a.ag_code,b.AG_NAME
order by a.Ag_CODE,b.AG_NAME;
```

This exception arises:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.doRun(DatasetPreviewTask.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.runDataset(DatasetPreviewTask.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.execute(DatasetPreviewTask.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetPreviewer.preview(DataSetPreviewer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.ResultSetPreviewPage$5.run(ResultSetPreviewPage.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot get the result set metadata.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
SQL error #1:ORA-00911: invalid character

 ;

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.newException(ExceptionHandler.java:52)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:108)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:84)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getRuntimeMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:414)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getProjectedColumns(PreparedStatement.java:377)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.doGetMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:347)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:563)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.execute(DataSourceQuery.java:972)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:503)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1208)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:233)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:178)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultMetaData(QueryResults.java:132)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.extractQuery(DatasetPreviewTask.java:352)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.doRun(DatasetPreviewTask.java:309)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
SQL error #1:ORA-00911: invalid character
```

;
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

```
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:481)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.getMetaUsingPolicy1(Statement.java:420)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.getMetaData(Statement.java:316)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.bidi.BidiStatement.getMetaData(BidiStatement.java:56)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.doGetMetaData(OdaQuery.java:423)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.getMetaData(OdaQuery.java:390)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.getRuntimeMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:407)
... 16 more
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:330)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:287)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:744)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:218)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:812)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1048)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:853)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1153)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3369)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3414)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:477)
... 22 more
```

Comment: please fix your typos and format your code properly

Answer (score 1):

Try aliasing your distinct count column - like so:

```
select a.ag_code , COUNT(distinct(a.usr_id)) as distinct_users, b.AG_NAME
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the ";" at the end of your query.  Adding the ";" might work in most tools (like PL/SQL Developer), but those tools are removing the ";" before sending it to oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This section of your error message

> **Caused by**: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot get the result set metadata.
>      org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
>   SQL error #1:ORA-00911: invalid character

Indicates your SQL is bad, Mark Bannister, has suggested a solution.  Dependining on how bad your SQL is this part of the error message can be more helpfull, callling out specific areas to review.